# Finding location of databinding errors in Android

Tags: android

If I have a spelling mistake in my databinding, Android Studio generates an error message that gives me no idea what the problem is or even where to find it. For example, in this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="net.gahfy.mvvmposts.ui.post.PostListViewModel" />
    </data>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mutableVisibility="@{viewModel.getLoadingVisibility()}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

If I misspell the method getLoadingVisibility, Android Studio generates the following error:

> An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.

This is totally useless. How would I even find this error? If I cannot easily find the error, then I think it's fair to say that databinding in Android should be avoided.

Comment: I am starting with data-binding and I can confirm that the error messages are the worst part of it. They are very vague, ambiguous and sometimes even misleading. I hope this gets answered!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `app:mutableVisibility="@{viewModel.getLoadingVisibility()}"`
 as databinding adapter? if no use `android:visibility="@{viewModel.getLoadingVisibility()}"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is hard to identify a spelling mistake in any of tag. But if you give some efforts to read the `BuildOutput` than you will identify what is wrong in your code.

[image]

You can simply find the layout file name and the wrong tag as describe in the given image.

May be it will help you to identify your problem.

Thank you